# Casting a generic class which is an object to it's type

Tags: c#, oop, generics

This is a class hierarchy question related to generics. I have a mostly derived class `MyClass3<T>` which is derived from `MyClass2<T>`. The class `MyClass2<T>` has a property called **MyProperty**.

I have a method **VerifyMyProperty** which accepts an object of type MyClass3. Since it is generic, it can be `MyClass3<A> or MyClass3<B> or MyClass3<C>`.

My question is, how can I cast *MyClass3 to MyClass2* to check the property *MyProperty*? Without generics, it would be easy as `var myClass2 = anyofMyClass as MyClass2`. With generics where the T can be A, B or C, how can I do the same casting?

```
public class MyClass3<T> : MyClass2<T>
{
....
}

public class MyClass2<T> : MyClass1
{
    T MyProperty { get; private set; }
}

public void VerifyMyProperty(object anyofMyClass)
{
    var myClass2 = anyofMyClass as MyClass2; // Finding the MyClass2. This line will return a compiler error.

    if (myClass2.MyProperty != null)
    {
       Console.Writeline("MyClass2.MYProperty is not null.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can cast an object of one type to another when they are inherently different; you will probably have to create a separate instance - though my knowledge is limited.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why should a class of try to validate the property of a totally different other type?

Comment: I introduced the method VerifyMyProperty as an example. The intent is to check the MyProperty's null status and display a message. The class where VerifyMyProperty resides in a framework method where I don't have much control to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: In your example `MyClass2` does not exists. Only `MyClass<T>` is a valid class.

So you might consider:

`var myClass2 = anyofMyClass as MyClass2<T>;`

In case `anyOfMyClass` must be able to contain a MyClass2 with another generic type, something goes wrong.

You might want to consider an implementation of a common and general interface with a property like:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    object MyProperty { get; }
}

public class MyClass2<T> : MyClass1, IMyInterface
{
    T MyProperty { get; private set; }
    object IMyInterface.MyProperty { get { return MyProperty; }}
}
```

When you implement this interface explicitly (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591(v=vs.71).aspx), you could solve your problem in the non-generic way:

```
var myClass2 = anyofMyClass as IMyInterface;
if (myClass2.MyProperty != null)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But both the solutions wont work. The type T needs to be provided during the compile time. So the compiler will give an error in this line 'var myClass2 = anyofMyClass as MyClass2<T>;' The second solution also does not work because the 'MyClass2<T>' will force 'MyProperty' to be of type 'object'.

Comment: If I derive MyClass2<T> from IMyInterface, the MyProperty should be of type object. I believe that's what you meant by explicit implementation. I don't want to do that because the other consumers of the MyClass3<T> wants to deal with the real type itself, not object.

Comment: No, what you are refering to is an IMPLICIT implementation. Explicit implementations are explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591(v=vs.71).aspx . I also updated the code for a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you Sir. That works and is an answer. But I'm looking at a different solution now after reviewing your answer. I may introduce a new interface called 'I' and all the types A, B, C derive from that interface I. Then I may able to use like 'var myClass2 = anyofMyClass as MyClass2<I>'. I don't know whether contra variant is a NEAT solution to this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question with all the new code. What is in the interface? Do you still want to read that property?

Comment: In this particular scenario, I'm interested only in the state whether it is null or not. The derived classes like MyClass3 will consume it's properties directly where I have more control, not in the method which accepts the object as the parameter.

Comment: I tried your approach as well as I type casted 'anyofMyClass' to 'dynamic' and then accessed the 'MyProperty' out of the 'dynamic' object. Using dynamic is very simple and it worked. But I can't reason why I need a dynamic here in this case, so I'm going with your suggestion.